# DataTables Invalid JSON response Error

Tags: php, mysql, json, datatables

I'm trying to learn how to use DataTable to implement it in my website. Firstly I've used https://editor.datatables.net/generator/ to generate a template, downloaded it and then started xampp, started apache and mysql and put the template there. Now I just started the index.html that the generator output and I get"

> DataTables warning: table id=Publications - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

I've followed the instruction and here is the error:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Exception: An SQL error occurred: 
>       SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\DataTablesEditor\php\lib\Database\Driver\Mysql\Query.php:108
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\DataTablesEditor\php\lib\Database\Query.php(950): 
>       DataTables\Database\DriverMysqlQuery->_exec()
>       #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\DataTablesEditor\php\lib\Database\Query.php(292): 
>       DataTables\Database\Query->_raw('CREATE TABLE IF...')
>       #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\DataTablesEditor\php\lib\Database\Database.php(394): 
>       DataTables\Database\Query->exec('CREATE TABLE IF...')
>       #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\DataTablesEditor\php\table.Publications.php(24): 
>       DataTables\Database->sql('CREATE TABLE IF...')
>       #4 {main}
>         thrown in
>    **C:\xampp\htdocs\DataTablesEditor\php\lib\Database\Driver\Mysql\Query.php** on line **108**

Any solution?

config.php

```
/* 
* DB connection script for Editor
* Created by http://editor.datatables.net/generator
*/

// Enable error reporting for debugging (remove for production)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

/*
* Edit the following with your database connection options
*/
$sql_details = array(
"type" => "Mysql",
"user" => "",
"pass" => "",
"host" => "",
"port" => "",
"db"   => "",
"dsn"  => "charset=utf8"
);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>DataTables Editor - Publications</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jq-2.2.4/pdfmake-0.1.27/dt-1.10.15/b-1.3.1/b-html5-1.3.1/b-print-1.3.1/r-2.1.1/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/generator-base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/editor.bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jq-2.2.4/pdfmake-0.1.27/dt-1.10.15/b-1.3.1/b-html5-1.3.1/b-print-1.3.1/r-2.1.1/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/editor.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/table.Publications.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="bootstrap">
    <div class="container">

        <h1>
            DataTables Editor <span>Publications</span>
        </h1>

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="Publications" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>test1</th>
                    <th>test2</th>
                    <th>test3</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>
            </table>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: It sounds like there is a problem with your db connection or your query. Can you paste any of your code?

Comment: I haven't changed anything that https://editor.datatables.net/generator/ output. I just ran the html file. I tried creating multiple templates and none of them worked on my machine, but on the datatables site they work.

Comment: I don't know what that code is but it isn't setting what database it should be using (or hasn't been told which to use)

Comment: OK. I'm trying to post some of the code, the problem is that the generator created a lot of files and I don't know which one to post.

Comment: I think in the `$sql_details` array you need to set `db` to the name of your database, along with the other connection details (user/pass)

Comment: Ok, so I set the localhost as host, the port is set to the apache from xampp, and i've also set the db name which in my case I think is publications (the name of the table). I don't get any error now, but when it starts, it stays with the table in loading.

Comment: I've added a picture with what i'm talking about. So if i press on the create button i doesn't happen anything. the window stays open.

Comment: All I can suggest is to check your browser's console log and your server's log file to look for more clues as to what isn't correct.